# Can NFS soft mounts cause silent corruption even after a successful "close" operation

Tags: linux, nfs

Almost everything I've read says that NFS soft mounts can cause silent corruption.  I assume this is because of the following scenario:

- user application writes to NFS
- NFS client accepts the write request and returns success to the user app
- NFS client has data queue/buffered waiting to be written to the NFS server
- Some problem prevents the queue/buffered data from being written (eg. NFS server goes down)

My question is, what happens with this scenario with NFS soft mounts:

- Same steps as above, but in addition...
- The user app continues to write more data on the same file handle
- The user app closes the file

Using soft mounts, will NFS flush it's cache for the just closed file?  And, if unable to do that, (because the NFS soft mount gives up because of errors), shouldn't the user app get an error back on the close command?

Ie., I'm wondering if a successful close on a soft mount NFS file guarantees that there was no *silent* corruption.

Later edit:
Looking at http://www.avidandrew.com/understanding-nfs-caching.html, it says,

> In NFSv3, the close() will cause the client to flush all data to stable storage. The client will also flush data to stable storage on a chmod, since that could potentially affect its ability to write back the data. It will not bother to do so for rename. An application should normally be able to rely on the data being safely on disk in both these situations provided that the server honours the NFS protocol (with a caveat that an ill-timed 'kill -9' could interrupt the process of flushing).

But then it also says that a NFS "commit" is ignored if the NFS volume was mounted with the async option (the default, as far as I can tell), so maybe this only applies if the NFS volume is explicitly mounted with the sync option?  But the NFS man page says the sync option doesn't do caching, which contradicts this.   Oh well.

Answer (score 3):

The [Linux NFS FAQ](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/) states that

> A8. What is close-to-open cache consistency?
>
> [...]
>
> When the application closes the file, the NFS client writes back any pending changes to the file so that the next opener can view the changes. This also gives the NFS client an opportunity to report any server write errors to the application via the return code from close(). This behavior is referred to as close-to-open cache consistency.

Answer (score 2):

I (with no proof) do not expect the `fclose()` causes any explicit flushing, nor to block while any flushing occurs.  You've simply relinquished the file handle to the *local* kernel.

https://serverfault.com/questions/9499/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-hard-versus-soft-mounts-in-unix